# ALSA : How to do stop and resume audio?

Tags: linux, audio, alsa

I need is to play a wave file multiple times. I don't want to call the hardware/software parameter settings APIs, each time the wave file is played again.

```
{start...play wave partially...stop}, {start...play wave partially...stop},  {start...play wave partially...stop}, ...
```

What apis are to be used here ? It is okay to drop the unplayed frames. When I checked alsa API, I can see lots of similar apis suspend/resume/stop .... What is the right combination to start and stop audio for above use case ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a PCM device has been stopped with `snd_pcm_drop`, you can restart it by calling `snd_pcm_prepare`, writing new data into the buffer, and then calling `snd_pcm_start` or using automatic start (which is enabled by default).